# Refresh ComboBox directory listing in WinForm, onClick for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, onclick

I have a set-up a Windows form that on completion creates a `.txt` document containing imputed data for the user on one form and then that form can then be opened into a `richTextBox` on another form using a `ComboBox` as a selection tool.

The problem I am having is that the `ComboBox` does not refresh the directory listings where the .txt documents are saved after a new `.txt` has been created and so the user has to restart the program before it shows up in the `ComboBox` listing, wondering how to solve this. Possibly force the `ComboBox` to refresh the listings `onClick` of a button?

Form with `ComboBox` selection method on:

```
 public Default()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
        foreach (string file in files)
            ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }

    private void moduleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewModule newmodule = new NewModule();

        newmodule.Show();
    }

    private void ModuleSelectorComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear(); //Clears previous Modules Text
        string fileName = (string)ModuleSelectorComboBox.SelectedItem;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Modules\", fileName + ".txt");

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            richTextBox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        else
            MessageBox.Show("There's been a problem. Please restart the program. \nError 1", "Error 1", //error 1 is file deleted while the program is running
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
```

*To add I want to avoid the using of the Dialog save/open file method and is why I am using the ComboBox to do this.*

Thanks in advance.

The form to create new .txt document (I don't see this as essentially needed I have just added it for reference):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            RichTextBox newbox = new RichTextBox();
        {
            String Saved_Module = Path.Combine("C:\\Modules", txtModuleName.Text + ".txt");
            newbox.AppendText(txtModuleName.Text + "\n" + ModuleDueDate.Text + "\n" + txtModuleInfo.Text + "\n" + txtModuleLO.Text);
            newbox.SaveFile(Saved_Module, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(@"C:\Modules", txtModuleName.Text));
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, encapsulate the logic of the combobox population in a method.

```
public Default()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadComboBox();
}

void LoadComboBox()
{
    ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Clear();
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
    foreach (string file in files)
        ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

I suggest to open the form as a dialog form using `ShowDialog` method
and set the `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK` in the `button5_Click` method.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox newbox = new RichTextBox();
    String Saved_Module = Path.Combine("C:\\Modules", txtModuleName.Text + ".txt");
    newbox.AppendText(txtModuleName.Text + "\n" + ModuleDueDate.Text + "\n" + txtModuleInfo.Text + "\n" + txtModuleLO.Text);
    newbox.SaveFile(Saved_Module, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(@"C:\Modules", txtModuleName.Text));
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

And then, based on the `DialogResult` load or do not load the combobox's items in the `moduleToolStripMenuItem_Click` method.

```
private void moduleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewModule newmodule = new NewModule();

    newmodule.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        LoadComboBox();
    }
}
```

Update:

If you don't want to use a Dialog, you can subscribe to an `FormClosing` event and update the combobox in a handler to the event.

```
private void moduleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewModule newmodule = new NewModule();
    newmodule.FormClosing += F_FormClosing
    newmodule.Show();
}

private void F_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    LoadComboBox();
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on a method without using Dialog?

Comment: @TCD You can do it without Dialog, just subscribing to an Closing event.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking out LoadComboBox as Valentin suggests, but using a FileSystemWatcher instantiated and disposed with the form to monitor the Modules directory and call LoadComboBox on any create/delete.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this for me? Sounds like the solution i've been looking for!